# Как вертикально отцентрировать меню при любом размере лого?

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap, выравнивание

Есть навигационная панель на основе `bootstrap 3`. Интересует: как с помощью стилей вертикально отцентрировать пункты меню так,чтобы **при любом размере изображения лого** они сохраняли свою центровку, притом решить это кроссбраузерно (без `flex`) ?
[ссылка на фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20406/)

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown active">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Getting started <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download">Download Bootstrap</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Examples</li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template">Basic template</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/">Starter template</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/">Grids</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/">Jumbotron</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/">Navbar</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/">Sign-in page</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/">Sticky footer</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/">Offcanvas</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/">Carousel</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/">Theme</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Compatibility</li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration">Migrating from 2.x to 3.0</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers">Browser support</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties">Third party support</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/css">CSS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/components">Components</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">JavaScript</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/customize">Customize</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Twitter Bootstrap 3.0</h1>
    <p class="lead">Starter template with CSS and JS included.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#fork">Fork this fiddle</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а где пункты меню? у меня они вообще не показываются

Comment: может так? - https://jsfiddle.net/hgfnarxL/

Comment: @Grundy в фидле можно растягивать-сужать экран

Comment: @soledar10 Думаю, стоит завернуть добавленные стили в `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) { }`, чтобы на смартфоне пользоваться штатным поведением бутстрапа.

Comment: @Gleb Kemarsky - вы правы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

   @import url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
  margin: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-header,
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: table-cell!important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown active">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Getting started <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download">Download Bootstrap</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Examples</li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template">Basic template</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/">Starter template</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/">Grids</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/">Jumbotron</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/">Navbar</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/">Sign-in page</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/">Sticky footer</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/">Offcanvas</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/">Carousel</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/">Theme</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Compatibility</li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration">Migrating from 2.x to 3.0</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers">Browser support</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties">Third party support</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/css">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/components">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/customize">Customize</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Twitter Bootstrap 3.0</h1>
    <p class="lead">Starter template with CSS and JS included.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#fork">Fork this fiddle</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте такой код в стили:

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Здесь `50px` - это высота лого, а `80px`- новая высота меню вместе с отступами.

`line-height: 50px;` отцентрирует пункты меню по вертикали.

Проверьте результат:

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown active">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Getting started <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download">Download Bootstrap</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Examples</li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template">Basic template</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/">Starter template</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/">Grids</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/">Jumbotron</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/">Navbar</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/">Sign-in page</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/">Sticky footer</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/">Offcanvas</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/">Carousel</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/">Theme</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Compatibility</li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration">Migrating from 2.x to 3.0</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers">Browser support</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties">Third party support</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/css">CSS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/components">Components</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">JavaScript</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/customize">Customize</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Twitter Bootstrap 3.0</h1>
    <p class="lead">Starter template with CSS and JS included.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#fork">Fork this fiddle</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: эхх.., ну почему не внимательно читаем вопрос? вот что получится, если поставить лого 100 на 100 к примеру - https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20411/

Comment: @Вася Предложенное решение подразумевает разовую ручную правку под конкретный лого. Понял, что неправильно воспринял задачу.

Comment: @Вася Если дополнять стили скриптом не возбраняется, то вычисление новых `height` и `line-height` можно [поручить скрипту](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/z3xk8kdh/). Уж очень не лежит душа перекурочивать бутсраповское меню в таблицы...

Comment: не желательно. @soledar10 в комментариях написал решение на стилях без таблиц